# How can I configure VIM so that files with extension .less are edited with zen-coding?

Tags: vim, less, emmet

How can I configure VIM so that files with extension .less are edited with zen-coding?

I can use within the zencoding notepad + + on windows normally. But now I want to use the same way inside vim.

Comment: It would have taken significant effort to put this question in a *less* clear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZenCoding is probably activated on a per-filetype basis, if that's the case, just type `:set filetype=css`.

If you want this setting to stick, add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.less set filetype=css
```

If you want to retain the normal features that go with `.less` files (if any) you can do `:set ft=less.css` but some plugins don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to write a comment, but found then something that could be an answer.

So I think the question is: How can I configure VIM so that files with extension `.less` are edited with [zen-coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/)?

At the official site for zen-coding, there are lists of editors that support zen-coding:

- Official
- third-party
- Unofficial

There for VIM, the following sites are mentioned:

- [Sparkup](http://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup)
- [Zen Coding for VIM](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981)

I have read into both, and both seem to expand shortcuts to HTML code, not to less-code. But perhaps I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: You're right, I need it: How can I configure VIM so that files with extension .less are edited with zen-coding?

I'm trying to edit the plugin Zen 'coding' to see if I can make the 'less' work.

thx

Comment: It seems that you have to write down the rules, what to expand to which. So you have 2 problems: not HTML output, but CSS; finding the rules that help to write CSS (in less style) speedier. The second is the more tough question, though ...

Comment: Well, I've been seeing in the actual coding that Zen plugin to extend the object with the rules. The html can be extended to haml, mustache and others. I will try to extend the css for the "less".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you could use Zencoding for css. I use it in Vim for html.It s great!I started using Less and I was wondering an hour ago ,If something like this existed. I guess it's something to work on.

Comment: ok I just tried it in Vim. vanilla css works in .less files. They extend normally using Zencoding. Also,I m new to stack overflow so I keep doing stupid things, like commenting my own comments. please indulge.